# Texturing with remesh modifier

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, uv

I find the remesh modifier *very* useful when placed above a displacement modifier in the modifier stack.  It saves the trouble of having to add loop cuts all over the place to get **square faces**.  And then I can also edit the mesh fluidly without having to dissolve and replace zillions of loop cuts.

But the only problem is that the remesh modifier eliminates all UV mapping I have done on the model.  I can use *object* mapping coordinates for boxy models but for non-squarish models, or when using a strongly patterned texture this does not work at all.  This especially does not work on cylindrical objects (most often wood logs or trees), which is where the remesh modifier is the most valuable.  With remesh I can lengthen/shorten the cylinder by simply moving its end face without having to dissolve all the loop cuts and add them again.

Here are some examples on a simple building-like model:

With no modifiers:

[image]

With remesh (desired result):

[image]

With subsurf, notice quads are not evenly sized or squares:

[image]

Any suggestions for other mapping techniques that work with remesh would be great.  I am also open to alternatives to remesh that accomplish a similar goal of creating even square faces as I use this technique a lot.

Answer (score 4):

If you're only using the Remesh modifier with the purposes of subdividing the model then the 'Subdivision Surface' modifier set to 'Simple' subdivision will probably be better.

This will subdivide the object in a similar manner to doing <kbd>W</kbd>> Subdivide in edit mode, but will not change the shape of the object like the default 'Subdivision Surface' modifier will:

[image]

At least on a simple test, it doesn't seem to distort the UVs and leaves them intact.

Comment: The purpose of the remesh isn't to subdivide the mesh, although it does that as well.  I use it to create *square faces* prior to displacement.  As you probably know, without square faces displacement (and sculpting) creates streaked, uneven displacement.

Comment: @PGmath subsurf (for now) guaranties quad faces in both modes

Comment: @user2859 the purpose is to create **evenly sized square** faces, not simply quads.  Otherwise displace modifier doesn't work properly.